# Magento + It is possible to show custom additional options on wishlist?

Tags: magento

I am using some custom options as additional options on site

I am using below code to show additional options to cart page using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. it is working fine

```
$additionalOptions[] = array(
                    'code' =>  'Personalize '.$j,
                    'label' => 'Personalize '.$j,
                    'value' =>  $personalizeData
                );

            $item->addOption(array(
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
//Here $personalizeData is my custom options array.
```

Now I want to show these options also on user's wishlist when user adds product to wishlist.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/wishlist/item/list.phtml` file

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): ?>
<?php $options = $this->helper('catalog/product_configuration')->getOptions($item); print_r($options); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: These custom options are those option which we added in products custom options. 
my custom options are not coming from backend(custom options of product).